# Working of await in Async await

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, async-await

Consider an asynchronous (`*Async` / `async`) function that is called twice, one time with `await` and other without it.

If I use await, will it wait until the asynchronous function is executed and then execute the next line?

```
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
//Some code here
```

And, if I don't use `await`, will it continue with executing the code below it without waiting for the asynchronous function to complete?

```
db.SaveChangesAsync();
//Some code here
```

Am, I right over here or await is mandatory when it comes to `async` functions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9):

> If I use await, will it wait till the `async` function is executed and then execute the next line.

That depends on the method returns. It returns a `Task[<T>]`, which represents a **future** value. If the `Task` is already completed, it keeps running synchronously. Otherwise, the remaining portion of the current method is added as a continuation - a delegate callback that is invoked when the asynchronous portion reports completion.

What it does **not** do, in either case, is block the calling thread while the asynchronous part continues.

> And, if I don't use await, will it continue with executing the code below it without waiting for the `async` function to complete.

Yes

> ...or await is mandatory when it comes to `async` functions?

When invoking them? Not mandatory, but it does make things convenient. Usually, such functions return a `Task[<T>]`, which can also be consumed via different code. You could use `.ContinueWith(...)`, `.Wait`, `.Result`, etc. Or you could just ignore the `Task` completely. The last is a bad idea, because exceptions on asynchronous functions need to go *somewhere*: very bad things happen if exceptions are not observed.

When *writing* them, however: if you write an `async` method and don't have an `await` keyword in there, the compiler will present a warning indicating that you're probably doing something wrong. Again, not strictly *mandatory*, but highly recommended.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks a lot. Cleared lots of doubts. +1 for you man :)

Comment: Regarding "very bad things happen if exceptions are not observed".  This gives the impression that something actively happens when ignoring the `Task`; when actually the exception is swallowed in this case (unless you use `async void`).  That said, I'd agree that the very bad thing that happened is you swallowed an exception and possibly left your program in an inconsistent state or ignored a bug.